# Is it possible to transfer coordinates of every vertex from one object to another?

Tags: vertices

Is there some way to transfer coordinates of every single vertex from one object to another? maybe an addon or something.. i tried Oscurart Copy Vertex Location but couldn't get it to work as shown in tutorial.